# Change OData value in Text control using JS and XML

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5, export-to-csv

The result initially showed in a Text Control and is multiplied by price,  quantity which are loaded from Odata and shown in the Input Control. The goal is, the result should be automatically updated in that Text control after new price and new quantity have been input into the Input Control. With the _onChange() I can change the properties (in this case are price and quantity) of OData(I have seen the updated properties and result in debugger modul). But the updated result just don't show up in the Text Control, does anyone have an idea?

**XML:**

```
<t:Column>
    <Text text="Price"/>
     <t:template>
        <Input id="price" value="{Prc}" editable="true"  change="_onChange"/>
     </t:template>
</t:Column>
<t:Column>
    <Text text="Quantity"/>
     <t:template>
        <Input id="quantity" value="{Qty}" editable="true"  change="_onChange"/>
     </t:template>
</t:Column>
```

**JS:**

```
  _onChange: function(oEvent){
  var test = oEvent.getSource();
  var path = test.getBindingContext().getPath();
  var obj = oModel.getProperty(path);

  var stringID=test.sId;
  //determine the current control using the predefined ID
  switch(oEvent!=null){
   case stringID.match("quantity")!=null
       //read the Input of quantity  in Input control
       obj.Qty = test._$input.context.value;   
       break;
   case stringID.match("price")!=null:
       //read the input of price in Input control
       obj.Prc = test._$input.context.value;   
       break;
};
var sum = parseInt(obj.Prc) * parseInt(obj.Qty);
obj.Result =sum.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. 
The problem was: the control id, which I have defined for input (in this case was `id="quantity"`), couldn't be found by the oEvent becase the control id was generated dynamically(in this case was e.g.: `id="__xmlview1--TBL_ep"`). In order to finid this dynamic id, we need to use `var oSTBL_EP = this.getView().byId("quantity");`, and than call the property sId of oSTBL_EP.
Only with a valid Id, the value can be visible in the text control

Answer (score 1):

If you have bound RESULT in the model, use that to update the model.